# Proteus Ares Layout - how do I reduce a 4 layer board to 2 layers?

Tags: proteus

I am working on a 4 layer board and I want to eliminate the 2 inner layers. Problem is that the autorouter never seems to get the message.

I have set layer pairs as top copper and all the others as bottom

In "Set Layers Usage" I have unticked everything

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried de-selecting the inner layers from Technology -> Set layer usage? And just double check that nothing is on those layers, no hidden power planes, or vias or traces you may have accidentally hidden when turning them off?

Comment: @MCG Yes. I gave up, deleted the tracks and tracked it all manually. Proteus is PITA and we are dumping it for something better in the near future. Most of the work I am doing is because the library footprints were wrong. It will be kept for legacy designs

Comment: If you update to the latest version, when searching for a part, if it doesn't have it, it'll search online for it on ultralibrarian or something similar and import the schematic symbol and footprint. It works really well. The auto router on it is a bit dodgy sometimes but I think proteus is a really good program personally

Comment: @MCG We have settled on SolidWorks since we already use it for mech design

Comment: Technology/Set LayerStackup/Stackup Wizard/No. of copper layesr/2 Fidel